# Does MD5 of a file changes if file date and time modified

Tags: python, md5, sha1, checksum, crc

I have a rar file which is collection of files. I have generated MD5 checksum on rar file using python code as below, then lets say rar file generated md5 is XXX. When I just extract rar file (no files modified/added) and again created rar file, then I observed that checksum has changed (to other than XXX).

```
import hashlib
hashlib.md5("filename.rar").hexdigest()
```

There is any algorithm like CRC, checksum, SHA1, etc where calculated checksum is same even if file date/time changed and no change in actual content of files?.

Comment: doesn't that hash the filename str, not the file?

Comment: The content of your rar file _is changing_.  It includes metadata, things like filenames and timestamps.

Comment: how exactly are you hashing? as @AnonCoward says the rar file likely will change between encodings anyhow, but hashlib.md5 'needs something supporting the buffer API'.  You're not just hashing `b"filename.rar"` are you?

Comment: This is a perfectly fine and useful question. How disappointing that some feel the need to downvote!

Answer (score 5):

Filesystem-level data is not naturally included when hashing a file because the filesystem is not part of the file!

However, when compressing many files together, a *new file* which is a *container with its own filesystem* to hold the others is created and they're all compressed together .. it's changes in this new filesystem which affect the final hash because the metadata associated with individual files is now included

```
single files:
A -> hash of A
B -> hash of B

multiple files together:
A,B -> C(A,B) -> hash of C(A,B)
```

This won't include filesystem-level information about `C`, but it will about `A` and `B` because it's necessary for them to be contained in `C`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to verify a signature on the contents of file in an archive is the compute the signature on the contents of that file. Not the archive.

You need to decompress the file and compute the signature. Compare that to the signature generated on the other end.

All archive formats already have a check on the data integrity, usually using a CRC. If that's good enough for you, then you're done. If however you need a cryptographically-strong signature, then you will need to compute something like an MD5 (a SHA256 would be better) on the uncompressed content.